# Plumbing problem

Tags: plumbing

I replace frozen water manifold in my well house.The pressure is holding @80psi. Still no water flow. Are my pipes frozen below the pump house floor? House sits on blockswith rocks pushed in between. Thinking passive air movement witch could have the pipes blocked with ice.

Comment: No one can answer this.  But yes you likely have something else frozen.

Comment: Seems likely. You might want to address that next summer so it does not happen again. Right now you need someone with a pipe thawing rig or some other way to get heat to the problem area, and then you need to keep enough water running to prevent re-freezing in the cold. Hay or strawbales set all around the pump-house basement might also help this year...